# How to check if an object is within an array's objects values?

Tags: python, django, if-statement, django-rest-framework, python-object

I'm building a server for Django Rest Framework. It models houses, contracts and owners. Basically, a `House` can have several `Contract`s and each `Contract` has an `Owner`.

I'm writing a custom permission for a `DetailView`s for the `House`s which should only allow the request, if you own the `House` (if you have a `Contract` for that `House` and you are the `Owner`.

Here is what I have so far:

```
class UserOwnsTheHouseSlugInUrlPermission(permissions.BasePermission):
    """
    Permission to check if the user is an owner for the given House.
    This permission needs a house_slug to be given in the url.
    """
    message = _(USER_IS_NOT_OWNER_PERMISSION_DENIED_MESSAGE)

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        owner = get_object_or_None(UserOwnerProfile, user=request.user)
        if owner and owner in obj.contracts.owner:
            return True

        return False
```

This code does not work. In JavaScript you could write:

```
if(obj.contracts.map(contract => contract.owner).includes(owner))
```

Or something similar. Python is not my main language, so I don't know how to express that condition in Python or Django.

How would you go about writing this? Thank you very much

Comment: What does "does not work" mean? Do you get an error? What is `obj` and `obj.contracts`? I don't think the problem is in Python syntax, `in` is the correct way to determine if an object is in a list; the problem is probably that `obj.contracts.owner` is not a list. You should show the models.

Comment: Not sufficient value is provided so I will bluff using `obj.contracts.owner.all()`

Comment: " does not work" is a totally useless description of a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comment, the issue is not one of Python syntax. The problem is that `obj.contracts` is presumably a ForeignKey, which returns a queryset; a queryset wouldn't have an `owner` attribute, that is a field on each of the model instances within the queryset.

Now you could do this to get a list of all the owners:

```
if owner and owner in obj.contracts.values_list('owner', flat=True)
```

but that would be the wrong solution. What you actually want to do is to *ask the database* if the owner is in the list of contract owners:

```
if owner and obj.contracts.filter(owner=owner).exists()
```

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I meant. I'm sorry that I worded the question poorly, it's hard to describe something if you don't know the words.